# Simulate Random Risk Battle

Tags: game, haskell, random, dice, battle-simulation

For Prof. Yorgey's 2013 Haskell [course](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/12-monads.pdf), I'm working on a homework to simulate a Risk battle.

```
type Army = Int

data Battlefield = Battlefield { attackers :: Army, defenders :: Army } 
                    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

In addition, Prof. Yorgey implement the following code to simulate the random throwing of dice:

```
newtype DieValue = DV { unDV :: Int } 
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Num)

first :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
first f (a, c) = (f a, c)

instance Random DieValue where
  random           = first DV . randomR (1,6)
  randomR (low,hi) = first DV . randomR (max 1 (unDV low), min 6 (unDV hi))

die :: Rand StdGen DieValue
die = getRandom
```

The second homework question asks to implement the `battle` function:

> which simulates a single battle (as explained above) between two
>   opposing armies. That is, it should simulate randomly rolling the
>   appropriate number of dice, interpreting the results, and updating the
>   two armies to reflect casualties. You may assume that each player will
>   attack or defend with the maximum number of units they are allowed.

And then for my implementation:

```
battle :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
battle bf = return $ battleOneRound bf

battleOneRound :: Battlefield -> Battlefield
battleOneRound bf = updateArmy bf (compete a_dice d_dice)
  where
    a_dice = rollDieN . getLegalAttackers $ (attackers bf)
    d_dice = rollDieN . getLegalDefenders $ (defenders bf)

rollDieN :: Army -> [DieValue]
rollDieN n 
  | n <= 0     = []
  | otherwise = evalRand die (mkStdGen (1000*n)) : rollDieN (n-1) 

type AttackersDice = [DieValue]
type DefendersDice = [DieValue]

-- defender must have at least 2 left at base
getLegalDefenders :: Army -> Army
getLegalDefenders n 
  | n >= 4    = 2
  | n == 3    = 1
  | otherwise = 0

-- attackers must have at least 1 left at base
getLegalAttackers :: Army -> Army
getLegalAttackers n 
  | n >= 4    = 3
  | n == 3    = 2
  | n == 2    = 1
  | otherwise = 0
```

**Testing**

```
ghci> let bf = battle $ Battlefield 10 20

ghci> (evalRand bf) $ mkStdGen 10
Battlefield {attackers = 8, defenders = 20}

ghci> (evalRand bf) $ mkStdGen 5
Battlefield {attackers = 8, defenders = 20}

ghci> (evalRand bf) $ mkStdGen 444444
Battlefield {attackers = 8, defenders = 20}
```

As you can see, the actual `StdGen` argument does not appear to have any impact on the battle results. That's because `rollDieN` uses `mkStdGen (1000*n)` to simulate random die throws.

Please critique this implementation. I'm not sure if I've achieved randomness in the `battle` function.

Comment: Just to clarify, your comment about `StdGen` not affecting the outcome, that is intended behavior, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. My only question is whether I've implemented the `battle` function in a way that aligns with the homework question.

Answer (score 6):

`rollDieN` doesn't look very random to me

```
*Risk> map unDV $ rollDieN 100
[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6]
```

This looks better:

```
*Risk> map unDV $ evalRand (replicateM 100 die) (mkStdGen 123456)
[4,5,2,3,5,6,2,3,2,5,4,5,5,5,1,1,6,6,2,3,2,5,5,3,4,1,3,1,
 3,2,4,4,3,2,2,6,2,2,3,1,6,6,4,5,3,6,6,6,5,2,2,1,6,3,6,3,
 6,3,6,5,6,5,1,1,1,2,1,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,2,4,1,5,4,
 4,2,1,1,5,1,4,2,6,5,3,5,2,3,6,1]
```

Now we can write a function that will return the two army's dice rolls

```
rollDice n = replicateM n die

battleTest :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen ([Int], [Int])
battleTest battlefield = do
    attackerRolls <- rollDice $ getLegalAttackers (attackers battlefield)
    defenderRolls <- rollDice $ getLegalDefenders (defenders battlefield)
    return (map unDV attackerRolls, map unDV defenderRolls)
```

And check that our output looks sane

```
*Risk> evalRand (battleTest (Battlefield 10 20)) (mkStdGen 12)
([6,3,2],[5,1])
*Risk> evalRand (battleTest (Battlefield 10 20)) (mkStdGen 123456)
([4,5,2],[3,5])
```

Now assuming a function to update the battlefield based on dice rolls, we just change it to

```
battle :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
battle battlefield = do
    attackerRolls <- rollDice $ getLegalAttackers (attackers battlefield)
    defenderRolls <- rollDice $ getLegalDefenders (defenders battlefield)
    return $ nextBattlefield attackerRolls defenderRolls battlefield
```

---

There's also a problem with `getLegalDefenders`. The homework says

> The defending player may defend with up to two units (or only one if
>   that is all they have).

So instead of

> ```
> getLegalDefenders :: Army -> Army
> getLegalDefenders n 
>   | n >= 4    = 2
>   | n == 3    = 1
>   | otherwise = 0
> ```

It should look like

```
getLegalDefenders :: Army -> Army
getLegalDefenders n 
  | n >= 2    = 2
  | n == 1    = 1
  | otherwise = 0
```

Or

```
getLegalDefenders n = max 0 (min 2 n)
```